# How to select records from table for a given date using sql server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a table in sql server
News(News_ID,Title,Article,Attatchment,Date)

I want to select all records of News table for any date provided by the user from asp.net c# using calender extender. The Date column in News table is of datetime.I have used following query:

select distinct  News.* from News where News.Date =@Date and 
                    News.Publish_Status=1 order by News.News_ID desc

but is not working when i am supplying any date no result is found.Please help me someone.

Comment: can you show me how you pass date to `@Date` field?

Comment: What's the datatype of Date field? If it is datetime, then you must have to truncate record time to 00:00:00. For this purpose simply convert @date parameter and Date field to int and then compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below Query:

```
select distinct News.* 
from News 
where CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),News.Date,101) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@Date,101) 
      and News.Publish_Status=1 
order by News.News_ID desc
```

It will work for any date formate.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query :

```
var fromDate = selectedDate.Date; // date with 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
var toDate = selectedDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1); // date with 23 hours, 59 minutes, 59 seconds

var query = "select distinct News.* from News where News.Date >= @fromDate  and News.Date <= @toDate and News.Publish_Status=1 order by News.News_ID desc
```